# Extracting parts of substring after a given target

Tags: ruby, regex

Given I have a string like (but not identical) to this:

```
"\ndigfodigjn \nfdoigoidfgj \nResidence\n123 N 74TH STREET \nPhiladelphia\nPA 19020\ngfhfgh gfhgfh \ndfijoij"
```

It will contain the substring "`Residence`". And I want to extract the 3 substrings after that. Each will be separated by a newline, but there is no guarantee of the total number of newlines in the entire string. The only guarantee is that after Residence substring, there will be three substrings that represent the address that are delimited by newlines.

I want this:

```
123 N 74TH STREET Philadelphia PA 19020
```

I am able to get the Residence substring this way:

```
str.split("\n").detect {|s| s =~ /^Residence/ }
```

But how can I get the substrings I want after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
> s="\ndigfodigjn \nfdoigoidfgj \nResidence\n123 N 74TH STREET \nPhiladelphia\nPA 19020\ngfhfgh gfhgfh \ndfijoij"
```

You can slice the multiline string with a [regex](http://rubular.com/r/sKkbTAaR3w) and capture the 3 lines after:

```
> s[/Residence\s*([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)/]
=> "Residence\n123 N 74TH STREET \nPhiladelphia\nPA 19020\n"
```

Or if you just want the capture group portion:

```
> s[/Residence\s*([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)/,1]
=> "123 N 74TH STREET \nPhiladelphia\nPA 19020\n"
```

Then you can split that on `"\n"` if you need three strings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dawg answer it will do the trick:

```
s[/Residence(\n[^\n]+){3}/].split("\n")[1..3]
```

Regex will look for `Residence`then it will look for 3 newlines followed for anything that is not a newline.

The resulting string can be split by new line and the 3 last elements will have the address

Answer (score 0):

Try with a lookback expression:

```
> str[/(?<=Residence)(\n[^\n]+){3}/].split("\n").join
=> "123 N 74TH STREET PhiladelphiaPA 19020"
```